# What is the domain of $(\arctan(x-1))^{1/(x-3)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I would like to know how to solve the domain for this function in real numbers:

$(\arctan(x-1))^{1/(x-3)}$

I usually know how to get to the domain, but this one caught me by surprise, where I don't even know where to begin or how to deal with it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.SE. Please use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/570189) to improve readability and increase your chances to get meaningful answers.

Comment: How do you usually get the domain of a function? I usually look for the values of $x$ that won't work, and eliminate them. Surely you can find some values of $x$ that won't work here. What kinds of things can "break" this expression?

Comment: @DavidK Well I solved it, but one thing was interesting. Just to write the expression in a different form affected the resulting domain, which was not immediately apparent at the beginning but was somehow implied by given conditions I guess? Or at least that's how I try to understand it.

Comment: @David K: Can you find the asked domain?

Comment: @Piquito Things get “interesting” when the value of the arc tangent is negative. The answer would depend on what definition of exponentiation you used and on what kinds of sets you consider to be suitable domains. It seems easier if you just delete that part of the number line from the domain.

Comment: @David K: Thanks for your reply I have just read. I have made a comment on the problem of Maranovot.

Answer (score 1):

Exponentiating with an arbitrary real exponent is only defined when the base is positive.

Thus you need $\arctan(x-1)>0$, besides the obvious $x-3\ne0$.

The first inequality is equivalent to $x>1$, so the domain is $(1,3)\cup(3,\infty)$.

Exponentiation $0^t$ might be considered defined, but only with positive exponent (pretty useless anyway). Not this case.

Some people also consider exponentiation defined for negative base, provided the exponent is rational, with a fairly complicated rule based on the expression of the rational with coprime numerator and denominator. I hope it's not your case.

Comment: When it comes to a function, of course it does, but when you want to establish particular values for which the function is well defined, then no. If this function is well defined for $x = 0.5$ then this $x$ belongs to the domain of the function.

Comment: @Piquito I disagree. Would you please carry out completely the domain? You preferred not to in your answer, for the precise reason that it is very impractical and, in my opinion, completely useless.

Comment: Thanks for your reply that I received by mail. I believe that your first line applies to the exponential function $a ^x$ in which $a$ is a constant but this is not the case here ($(-1)^{1/3}=-1$, for example,  is not a silly equality) . What is the domain of a real function $f (x)$? It is the complete set of possible values of the independent variable for which $f (x)$ is well defined, the set of all possible $x$-values which will make the function "work ", then $x=0$ belongs to the required domain and so is for many other not obvious values. (suite)

Comment: The purpose of this problem is to find a domain which I believe  it is not immediate  to find. On the other hand, the fact of being completely useless has never been a strong reason in mathematics. Regards. (Sorry for bad English).

Comment: @Piquito I don't think so.

Comment: I respect your position. I hope you respect mine which wants to keep in line with the definition domain of a function. Greetings (I put @egreg at the beginning but it does not come out).

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment about your problem in which I have some doubts. Putting $$y=(\arctan(x-1))^{1/(x-3)}\tag 1$$ you can consider the equivalent expression (where $y\ne 0$) $$y^{x-1}=y^2\arctan(x-1)\tag 2$$
 From $(1)$ it easily follows that  $x=1$ and $x=3$ are not in the domain (*you have* $\arctan 2\approx 63,434949^{\circ}$ *and* $y$ *becomes infinite* *in both cases*). Besides, no problem for all element of $D_1=]1,3[\space\cup\space]3, +\infty[$ and plotting with Desmos the corresponding curve $(1)$ (or $(2)$ if you want because both have the same graphic), this $D_1$ is apparently given as the required domain.

[image]

I have put expression $(2)$ in case it could give some help to really finish because $D_1$ above is not the whole domain. We have for example:
$x=0$ gives $$(\arctan (-1))^{-\frac13}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\arctan(- 1)}}=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{\arctan( 1)}}=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{\pi}{4}}}\approx -1.083852$$ so $x=0$ belongs to the domain but $0\notin D_1$ There is a lot of other values of $x$ for which the function is well defined, for example:

$$f(0.1)\approx 1.113149\\f(0.5)\approx 1.359955\\f(-0.9)\approx 0.978994\\f(-6.3)\approx-0.961934\\f(-6.2)\text { is undefined }$$ For $x=-1$ we have $f(-1)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{-\arctan 2}}\notin\mathbb R$ and similarly the function is undefined for $x=-(2n+1)$ but for example for $x=-2$ one has $f(-2)\approx -0.956498$.

We can see that the domain $D_1$ apparently given by Desmos is not complete. But then what is this domain? Here I stop this comment.